# Issue deploying Nuxt static site to Netlify using Github

Tags: github, nuxt.js, netlify, bootstrap-vue, static-site-generation

I'm having issues deploying my Nuxt static site (build with Bootstrap Vue and using Wordpress Rest API) to Netlify using Github. When I deploy it manually it works just as expected. But when I use Github it gives me the "Page Not Found-message" for most of the pages and for those pages that don't get that error it doesn't provide all the page content.

I have followed the Nuxt configure for a statically generated site: [https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/netlify/#for-a-statically-generated-site][1]. I have also tried to change the NODE_VERSION environment variable but without success. Does anyone have a suggestion for a solution to this problem?

This is the deploy log from Netlify

````
11:26:18 AM: build-image version: a6bb34428a07e7de82f4df5dfe1843fbde91f670 (focal)
11:26:18 AM: build-image tag: v4.5.1
11:26:18 AM: buildbot version: 5284b4d1b8b4cf691b29019968d8e4eb3089acdd
11:26:18 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:26:18 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:26:18 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:26:19 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:26:19 AM: git clone https://github.com/DianaNilsson/devmore-headless-wp
11:26:19 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:26:20 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
11:26:21 AM: Starting build script
11:26:21 AM: Installing dependencies
11:26:21 AM: Python version set to 2.7
11:26:22 AM: v16.13.1 is already installed.
11:26:23 AM: Now using node v16.13.1 (npm v8.1.2)
11:26:23 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
11:26:23 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
11:26:23 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
11:26:25 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
11:26:25 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
11:26:25 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:26:25 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:26:26 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.1.2
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
11:26:29 AM: npm WARN old lockfile
11:26:52 AM: npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
11:26:53 AM: npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
11:26:53 AM: npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
11:27:00 AM: npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
11:27:08 AM: npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
11:27:10 AM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
11:27:11 AM: npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
11:27:14 AM: npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
11:27:17 AM: added 1229 packages, and audited 1230 packages in 50s
11:27:17 AM: 104 packages are looking for funding
11:27:17 AM:   run `npm fund` for details
11:27:17 AM: 15 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 8 high)
11:27:17 AM: To address issues that do not require attention, run:
11:27:17 AM:   npm audit fix
11:27:17 AM: To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
11:27:17 AM:   npm audit fix --force
11:27:17 AM: Run `npm audit` for details.
11:27:17 AM: NPM modules installed
11:27:18 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
11:27:18 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
11:27:18 AM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
11:27:18 AM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
11:27:18 AM: Installing missing commands
11:27:18 AM: Verify run directory
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:27:20 AM:   Netlify Build                                                 
11:27:20 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ❯ Version
11:27:20 AM:   @netlify/build 20.3.1
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ❯ Flags
11:27:20 AM:   baseRelDir: true
11:27:20 AM:   buildId: 61b9c2c801d254a8c2bc2a45
11:27:20 AM:   deployId: 61b9c2c801d254a8c2bc2a47
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ❯ Current directory
11:27:20 AM:   /opt/build/repo
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ❯ Config file
11:27:20 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ❯ Context
11:27:20 AM:   production
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:27:20 AM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
11:27:20 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:27:20 AM: ​
11:27:20 AM: $ npm run generate
11:27:21 AM: > devmore-headless-wp@1.0.0 generate
11:27:21 AM: > nuxt generate
11:27:42 AM: [error] [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /opt/build/repo/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/icons/icons.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
11:28:12 AM: [error]  /kontakt
11:28:12 AM: 
11:28:12 AM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
11:28:12 AM:     at a.render (pages/kontakt.vue?a191:1:0)
11:28:12 AM:     at a.t._render (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:35346)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70854
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM:     at to (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67708)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70928
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM:     at to (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67708)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70928
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM: [error]  /om-oss
11:28:12 AM: 
11:28:12 AM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
11:28:12 AM:     at a.render (pages/om-oss.vue?bc3a:1:0)
11:28:12 AM:     at a.t._render (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:35346)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70854
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM:     at to (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67708)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70928
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM:     at to (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67708)
11:28:12 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70928
11:28:12 AM:     at eo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67418)
11:28:12 AM:     at oo (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70830)
11:28:12 AM:     at no (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70461)
11:28:12 AM: [error]  /
11:28:12 AM: 
11:28:12 AM: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
11:28:12 AM:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
11:28:12 AM: [error] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
11:28:12 AM:   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: (build.command completed in 52.6s)
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:28:13 AM:   2. Deploy site                                                
11:28:13 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:28:13 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'dist'
11:28:13 AM: Creating deploy tree 
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: Creating deploy upload records
11:28:13 AM: 3 new files to upload
11:28:13 AM: 0 new functions to upload
11:28:13 AM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: (Deploy site completed in 663ms)
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:28:13 AM:   Netlify Build Complete                                        
11:28:13 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:28:13 AM: ​
11:28:13 AM: (Netlify Build completed in 53.5s)
11:28:14 AM: Starting post processing
11:28:14 AM: Post processing - HTML
11:28:14 AM: Caching artifacts
11:28:14 AM: Started saving node modules
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving node modules
11:28:14 AM: Started saving build plugins
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving build plugins
11:28:14 AM: Started saving pip cache
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving pip cache
11:28:14 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
11:28:14 AM: Post processing - header rules
11:28:14 AM: Started saving go dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
11:28:14 AM: Post processing - redirect rules
11:28:14 AM: Post processing done
11:28:14 AM: Site is live ✨
11:28:16 AM: Build script success
11:28:38 AM: Finished processing build request in 2m19.82235889s```
````

Comment: Does it work if you generate and start it locally?

Comment: What do you mean by `deploy manually`too?

Comment: Yes it works when I generate it and  start it locally. It also works if I drag and drop the dist folder to the deploy area of Netlify (that's what I meant by manual deploying). But when Netlify tries to build (generate) it from Github it just fails. The build succeed but it is missing a lot of pages and content. This is the [repo]https://github.com/DianaNilsson/devmore-headless-wp

Comment: What version of NPM/Node are you using locally? Also, did you set all the variables and so on? Hm, looks like you're using NPM v8. Maybe it's not supported by Netlify? Could you maybe trip to deploy it with `yarn`? Did you inspected the `title` error in your `kontakt.vue` file?

Comment: I tried switching to Yarn but got the same problem (it still works fine to generate and start locally just like NPM). Which variables do you mean? Yes I can't see anything wrong with it, I think that error depends on that no data from store is provided due to this issue.

Comment: Do you have an `.env` file?

Comment: Nope, I haven't.

Comment: Here is a fork of your project: https://github.com/kissu/devmore-headless-wp/commit/47b7bfcd9f80e09ccfe86e65e8d5ca8e84165d7c I fixed 2 pages who were indeed broken because of a `.key` on something `undefined`. Couldn't fix the `/` because you rely on some backend. Also, I'm not really sure how you plan to host it on Netlify with those kind of endpoints: `http://localhost/devmore/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`. This is a local address so far, of course it will fail when generating the pages because you don't have a locally running backend server on Netlify.

Comment: Thank you for helping me come up with the answer to this problem! Of course Github can not use my local MAMP server to access the Wordpress Rest API. That's why it only worked when I deployed manually with drag and drop. Hopefully it works if I move  the local Wordpress install to a live URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you try to deploy with your local server on Netlify. You'll need to deploy the backend too.